# Deserialize a string to json

Tags: json, deserialization

I want to know whether deserialize converts json to string or string to json.I need my string to be returned as Json so i used deserialize, but unsure about its syntax.Can anyone direct me correctly.
My code

```
        JavaScriptSerializer datajson = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var objec = datajson.Deserialize<string>(data);
     return Json(objec,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I used stringify to change my json data and sent as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialisation is the act of taking objects and turning them into something more persistable or communicable, i.e. turning objects into JSON, XML or binary data.

Deserialisation is the act of taking serialised data and turning it back into objects.

So in your case, if you want to turn your objects/variables into JSON, the process is called serialisation.

Your code, assuming it is MVC C# (you may wish to add these tags to your original post), appears to be deserialising a JSON encoded string into a string, then serialising it back to JSON again when it returns the view.  I'm not sure why you would want to do this.  You should be able to simply do:

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: I tried giving :                                              return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                  but it just returns me string.I want to pass my json data as datasource for grid.so i need Json to be return from controller.

Comment: If you're getting a string back from your action method this is correct, as the code will serialise your data into a JSON string.  If you wish to convert this back to actual JavaScript Objects, you may wish to use `JSON.Parse()` in your JavaScript.